# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.trigger')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have loaded the jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js file in my javascript.

But when I run my code:

```
<script>
  $('.css').datepicker().datepicker(val);
</script>
```

I get an error like this in the console:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'c.trigger') in jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js (line 491)
```

not sure, why this happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual code you're running that causes the error?

Comment: Make you loaded jQuery UI only one time and you used the corresponding jQuery Core version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<script>
  $('.css').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker(val);
</script>
```

Try making your selector more specific. Do you want to run `.datepicker()` on all alements that have class `css`?

**EDITED:**

***Hey, you need to load jQuery itself not only jQuery UI!***

Make sure to embed it:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't help. I guess I'm missing some lib

Comment: How many `datepicker()`'s are you trying to load? (..edited my answer)

Comment: Aren't you using frames by any chance?

Comment: oh.. and you didn't load `jQuery` but `jQuery-UI`.